# What's the point of a DataContract in WCF?

Tags: wcf

VS.net creates a template when you create a WCF project.

It adds a class to the iService1.cs file:

```
// Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to
// add composite types to service operations.
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

Since a WCF service can return any user defined class, why use a DataContract and CompositeType class?

I can return something like:

```
 [OperationContract]
MyUserCollection GetUsers();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you have .NET on both ends of the wire, that's just fine. What if you have a Java client calling your service? If you put your data inside DataContracts, that information gets stored in the WSDL/XSD metadata and can be used by clients other than .NET, too.

Comment: I found the comment of marc_s is most useful and straightforward but while reading other answers I found the one by WolveFred which confused me. So could you please clarify it. Upvoted because it is still most straightforward answer.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The DataContract is just a formal definition of a type that can be understood on both sides of the service boundary.

If you return, as in your example, a "MyUserCollection" object, the consumers of your service will need to reference the innards of your service/system, which is a violation of the SOA tenet of explicit boundaries.  By using a DataContract, you are publishing the structure of your return types in a loosely-coupled way.

Comment: My WCF is being consumed by apps written by me, so in all practical purposes it should be ok (to voilate SOA).  Do you concurr?

Comment: You probably could, but why would you want to? Adding the attribute is painless and is the recommended way to work with WCF.

Comment: Scott, so I just add my MyUserCollection to the CompositeType class and bingo!?

Comment: You may need to add a [KnownType(MyUserCollection)] attribute to the CompositeType class. I would try it first without one; if it doesn't work you will get an exception saying to add MyUserCollection to the list of known types, in which case just add the attribute.

Comment: So it would not be needed if the service were serving JSON?

Comment: @ScottDorman, for me classes I would be using is referenced from another library. So is there any need to add the [DataContract] attribute? and if so, how?

Comment: The way I would recommend in .NET would be to define the DataContracts in their own assembly, which is separate from your service implementation and can be referenced both by both your service implementation and consumers of it.  You can then use the DataContracts as the structure for your messages into and out of the service, and by having the DataContract you get built-in validation and scaffolding support from WCF.

Comment: @osagie Are you saying that the classes you want to use are in another library and you don't have source code access to it? If so, then you really can't add the attribute since you aren't able to modify the source code.

Answer (score 27):

Another interesting thing to notice, is if you decorate your code with DataContract, you have a lot of control about what the client can see and must send back to your service. For example:

```
[DataContract]
public class SampleClass
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public int MyRequiredProperty { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int MyOptionalProperty { get; set; }

    public int MyInternalProperty { get; set; }
}
```

On the example above, you defined that when receiving data, you MUST have MyRequiredProperty, and you can have or not MyOptionalProperty. Also, the client will never see MyInternalProperty (this can be for example some property that helps with your logic internally, but you don't want it being exposed at the client level).

Answer (score 12):

There is another important use, You can change the Name of class and properties. It's a handy feature during serialization and deserialization.

```
[DataContract(Name="EmployeeName")]
public class Person
{
   [DataMember(Name="FullName")]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [DataMember(Name="HomeAddress")]
   public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the poster who said "The DataContract is just a formal definition of a type that can be understood on both sides of the service boundary."

The keyword here is "type".  In .NET, a type is an object that can have fields, properties, and methods.  However, when you decorate a class with `DataContract` in your WCF service, the result is not the class being magically transplanted into the calling code; not by a long shot!  In the calling code, you will have a "proxy" class.  The proxy class receives XML that represents the contents of the data contract.  The calling code can receive these XML values through the proxy class, but it does *not* give the calling code access to the innards of the class decorate with `datacontract`.

Comment: Your statement "a type is an object" is confusing and misleading. Object is a type of type, as Integers and Strings are types. Just for clarity, type is an identifier of which Object is one, String another, as is Integer, Boolean etc.

Answer (score 2):

For answering to "marc_s" :

> "If you have .NET on both ends of the
>   wire, that's just fine. What if you
>   have a Java client calling your
>   service? If you put your data inside
>   DataContracts, that information gets
>   stored in the WSDL/XSD metadata and
>   can be used by clients other than
>   .NET, too."

I think it is false. Let's try to do this :

1. Use the default example of WCF
   project with a class with 
   DataContract attributes on classes
   and DataMember on members, and a
   method which returns this type.
2. Build it and display the wsdl. The xsd contains the CompositeType definition. OK.
3. Now let's remove all attributes DataContract and DataMember
4. Build it and display the wsdl. The xsd still contains the ComposityType definition ! (it is more obvious with a SCM soft, which shows no difference in files between steps 2 and 4)

So a Java client should manage this, without DataContract and DataMember ! Am I wrong or what ?

Comment: You're not wrong, Walter.  (I kid, I kid)  The deal is that your consumer still needs to know format, correct?  If you're in .NET-land on both sides, you're fine by simply referencing the object.  You can't import a .NET object into Java [readily], so you have to expose the format another way.  Not sure why 4 would be true -- I believe the deal is that it shouldn't, correct?  Though admittedly I'm mainly here for the chance to quote El Duderino.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not often used, we could use [DataContract] to pass through private variables. The DataContractSerializer will serialize/deserialize only publicly visible types if [DataContract] attribute is not used.

```
[DataContract]
public class SampleClass
{    
    [DataMember]
    private int MyPrivateProperty { get; set; }
}
```

(Note: If you are generating a proxy then private members are exposed as public)