# Hide public properties from DataContract

Tags: wcf, datacontract, datamember

I removed [DataMember] attribute from all of my public properties, yet the properties are still showing up in the results of my WCF operations.  I found this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303013/whats-the-point-of-a-datacontract-in-wcf) that explains if .Net is on both ends of the wire, then DataMember doesn't have much of an effect on determining what properties are included in the DataContract.

So, how do you exclude public properties from being included in WCF results?

Thanks

Comment: With attribute IgnoreDataMember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways that the serialization in WCF can work. They are outlined [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/02/22/536747.aspx). Note that [Serializable] classes can also be used.

Note the last item in that list: Starting with 3.5 SP1, classes that are not annotated with any option would still be serializable by the WCF infrastructure. If you do that, however, you're left with no way to control how that serialization happens and what properties are serialized (which is why I personally feel that option was a mistake to add, but that's another story).

Is there any reason why you removed the [DataContract][DataMember] attributes?

Comment: I removed [DataContract][DataMember] attributes to test what would happen.  I'm disappointed to learn that they have no control over what properties are included.  So, how would you exclude a public property from being serialized using WCF?   Thanks for the response.

Comment: Well, you can either use [Serializable] + [NonSerializable], or use [DataContract] + [DataMember] explicitly. One very big reason why you shouldn't try to avoid [DataContract] is simply that it provides a way to explicitly control the order of fields in the contract (through the Order property of [DataMember], which is *very* important for versioning (because the default order in WCF is alphabetical order, not the order of declaration)