# How to pass my own class using WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I have simple WCF Service Application (based on this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx ).

Is it possible to write function that passes/returns my own class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, till the time your class is Serializable, you can pass it back. Recommended way is to use Data Contracts. See

- [Using Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx)
- [What's the point of a DataContract in WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303013/whats-the-point-of-a-datacontract-in-wcf)