# Data Contract in WCF

Tags: wcf

Can somebody please explain me the main use of data contract. 
I am not very much clear definitions given on MSDN and many more website Can you please explain me with a scenario or example so that it can be understood in a better way.

Thanks,
Monika

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303013/whats-the-point-of-a-datacontract-in-wcf

Comment: Whenever you have a WCF service that needs to return a class (not just a single `int` or `string`), you need to decorate that with `[DataContract]` so that the service will know to serialize it over the wire

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you a book i used to learn the basics and understand how WCF works and what are the contracts and what are the differences between them.

Wrox - Professional WCF 4: Windows Communication Foundation with .NET 4

It's a great book and easy to understand and has a lot of examples for you.

DataContract is used on a class and DataMemeber is used on it's properties so when you call the WCF service it uses this Contracts to serialize and send your class between the Client and Server side. With the Contracts your Client side can use then the class and it's data.