# CompositeType in WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

i can't understand what exactly is auto generated CompositeType in my simple WCF library.
I can't find any references about this type in microsoft site.

Comment: It's just an example to show you the use of a data contract (as opposed to using value types like the first example shows).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the point of a DataContract in WCF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303013/whats-the-point-of-a-datacontract-in-wcf)